# Undefined control sequence in input file (with \citeauthor and \citeyear)?

Tags: input

I have a main.tex file which is including other tex files in order to have a better overview over my file. Here is how the main.tex looks like:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}

 \date{}
 \graphicspath{{../figures/}}


 \newcommand\Mycite[1]{%
 (\citeauthor{#1},~\citeyear{#1})}

 \begin{document}
 \nocite{*}

 \input{second_latex_file}
 \bibliographystyle{plain} 
 \bibliography{literature}
 \end{document}
```

and in the second_latex_file.tex I am trying to use the defined command Mycite, but I am still getting the error "undefined control sequence Mycite.. 
The file second_latex_file.tex  has no preambles, it just starts with a text! So like:

```
 \chapter{Second chapter}
 ......some text here
.... \Mycite{something}
```

I tried to copy the command into this file, but of course then I get the error message "command already defined". Does someone know what I have to do in this case :S?

Comment: `\citeauthor` **and** `\citeyear` are unknown, that's why there are complains, so the error is within `\Mycite`, not the command `\Mycite` itself

Answer (score 8):

you need `\usepackage{natbib}` for `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` to work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{natbib}

 \date{}
 \graphicspath{{../figures/}}


 \newcommand{\Mycite}[1]{%
 (\citeauthor{#1},~\citeyear{#1})}

 \begin{document}
 \nocite{*}

 \Mycite{something}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I am so blind! Thanks a lot! I commented it out and yes... didn't manage to find it out myself. Thanks!

Comment: @user63716 You're welcome :)